# How can I run Matlab functions over multiple paired inputs and output a Matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix, statistics, anonymous-function, mle

I am new to Matlab, and so far I learned how to evaluate functions of multiple var.s over a *single* vector of data, as in the following example,

```
>>data = [1,2,3,4,2,2.5,2.9,1.8,-1,1.8]
>>fun=@(x) (1/(sqrt(2*pi)*x(2)))*exp((-(data-x(1)).^2)/(2*x(2)^2)) %A Normal distribution
>>fun([1,2])

Columns 1 through 9

    0.1995    0.1760    0.1210    0.0648    0.1760    0.1506    0.1270    0.1841    0.1210

  Column 10

    0.1841
```

This works as expected, but what about a function like the following, *with multiple data sources,*

```
>>data1 = [1,2,3,4,2,2.5,2.9,1.8,-1,1.8]
>>data2 = [1,2,3.1,4.1,2.1,2.51,3.1,-1,1.9,2] 
>>p = .5092
>>fun = @(x) (1/(2*pi*x(2)*x(4)*sqrt(1-p^2))) * exp( (-1/(2-2*p^2)) * ( (data1-x(1)).^2/(x(3)^2) + (data2-x(2)).^2/(x(4)^2) - (2*p(data1-x(1))*(data2-x(2)))/(x(3)*x(4)) ) ) % A joint-probability distribution
>>fun([1,2,3,4])

Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.

Error in
@(x)(1/(2*pi*x(2) . . .
```

This last equation is just a joint probability distribution, and every observation is made up of a paired x and y value. How would I run this and similar functions over both data1 and data2 at the same time, being iterated over the same index for both of them, one number at a time, producing a matrix of outputs?

The reason I can't simply run a loop is because I need to enter this function into a `fminunc()` function optimization process and have it be able to evaluate the F. for each pair of values.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote `2*p(data1-x(1))` then `p` is viewed as vector, change this to `2*p.*(data1-x(1))`. A second error is `(data1-x(1))*(data2-x(2))`. This is a matrix multiplication, and since the dimensions don't match will give an error. I assume you want a scalar multiplication, then again add the `.` so it becomes `(data1-x(1)).*(data2-x(2))`

Comment: When exactly should a "." be placed for element-wise operations? Is it everywhere around any vector, even for addition/subtraction, or are there more rules I should be aware of?

Comment: @Coolio2654 The dot is only for scalar multiplication or division when vectors/matrices are involved.

Comment: Ok, my code runs now if I define my two `data()`'s within my anonymous function the way you suggested. I just have one more question I hope you can answer. The function I'm creating to run this whole process takes the `data` as an input, but if there's more than one data source of observations (as in this situation), I don't know how to allow the function to accept random amounts of `data`'s.

So is there a way to zip up/combine any two observations sources into one file with two dimensions, and have the function run over that?

Comment: @Coolio2654 Do you mean combining `data1` and `data2` in 1 variable data? That is surely possible. If you have 2 row vectors of equal length (let's say 1xn) then `data = [data1;data2]` is a 2xn matrix with the 1st row`data1` and the 2nd row`data2`. In case of 2 column vectors it is `data = [data1 data2]`. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, and run some function `fun()` over both columns, treating either as a separate data source corresponding to data1, data2, ... .

I combined both of them into one file as you said, but it doesn't work as the function doesn't recognize the information is there. Is there some way to get the function to look within a specific dimensions of a matrix for all of it's observation sets?

Comment: @Coolio2654 you mean addressing `data1` and `data2`? Just the same as you would address the rows of a matrix. So for `data` a 2xn matrix with 1st row `data1`, 2nd `data2`: `data1==data(1,:)` and `data2==data(1,:)`.